# Where Doctrine saves cache in Zend Framework 3 and how to change it's location?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I need to change Doctrine cache folder to my custom folder in Zend Framework 3?
But I can't find - where is default cache folder?
And how I can to configure this path in my project?

Comment: Hi, not 100% sure about zf3 but on zf2 it goes under data/DoctrineORMModule. Assuming they have not change the core architectural principles for zf3, it should still be there. As for changing, this should be done under 'doctrine' key in config array. have a look at doctine website for exact syntax.

Comment: In data/DoctrineORMModule there is only one directory - Proxy. That's it? If it is so I can change it by 'proxy_dir' key. But I'm not sure I'm right.

Comment: proxy objects is how doctrine stores it's DB queries this is the main caching method for doctrine.  It may have some secondary caching mechanism, but I have never used that, so can not help out muchwith that one.